# scroll image with continuous scrolling using marquee tag

Tags: html, image

I am using a `<marquee>` tag for continues moving of image  horizontally. Suppose I have a 5 images than it moving fine but after completion of last image move there is a big gap to start scrolling from 1 st image.How can i mange this?

My code is some thing like that:

```
<marquee direction="right">
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
</marquee>
```

Comment: Can you make some code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Alright, I think I misunderstood your "gap" in the first place. `Marquee` does work this way, no matter how "short" it is. If you want to "fill the gap", you'll have to make your own `div` that simulates your way. A general method would be continuously moving the first element to last when it's out of sight.

Answer (score 2):

Marquee (`<marquee>`) is a deprecated and not a valid HTML tag. You can use many jQuery plugins to do. One of it, is [jQuery News Ticker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/). There are many more!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot scroll images continuously using the HTML marquee tag - it must have JavaScript added for the continuous scrolling functionality.

There is a JavaScript plugin called [crawler.js](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?69888-Text-and-Image-Crawler-amp-FancyBox&p=278161#post278161) available on the dynamic drive forum for achieving this functionality. This plugin was created by John Davenport Scheuer and has been modified over time to suit new browsers.

I have also implemented this plugin into my blog to document all the steps to use this plugin. Here is the sample code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/crawler.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>

<div id="mycrawler2" style="margin-top: -3px; " class="productswesupport">
    <img src="assets/images/products/ie.png" />
    <img src="assets/images/products/browser.png" />
    <img src="assets/images/products/chrome.png" />
    <img src="assets/images/products/safari.png" />
</div>
```

Here is the plugin configration:

```
marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: 'mycrawler2',
    style: {
    },
    inc: 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
    mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    moveatleast: 2,
    neutral: 150,
    savedirection: true,
    random: true
});
```

Comment: You can see a demo here http://technicalpixel.com/continous-horizontal-jquery-image-marquee/

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the marquee width related to 5 images total width. It works fine

ex: `<marquee style="width:700px"></marquee>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<marquee behavior="" Height="200px"  direction="up" scroll onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);this.stop();" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 3, 0);this.start();" scrollamount="3" valign="center">

    <img src="images/a.jpg">
        <img src="images/a.jpg">
        <img src="images/a.jpg">
        <img src="images/a.jpg">
        <img src="images/a.jpg">
        <img src="images/a.jpg">
    </marquee>
```